# .NET Design: Bubbling up exceptions to better refactor entity consumers, is it a good practice?

Tags: .net, exception, architecture, api-design

Not sure it's best place to discuss this question since it's kinda broad so I'm gonna attempt to narrow down the scope a bit.

**My Background**
Back the other day, I asked a couple of questions about some design decisions in to the manager of the team I recently joined. I'm working on a trading application for a corporate investment bank and there is quite a lot of legacy code (like in any other software application that has survived to changes for more than 5 years).

To make it short, it seems a common practice here to not throw any exception and **not** really checking the arguments passed to a method or to a constructor. While I agree that there are cases where arguments check is worthless, it might help to throw an exception when certain types or range of values cannot work with you method.

People are using TDD here and I'm fine with that but I don't think everything can be prevented with that practice. But swallowing exceptions and letting other disasters happen in silence is in no way any better, tests help in many to prevent this kind of problem to occur, but not always.

It's always a matter a context, but in my past a job putting exceptions helped my team a lot to improve the code quality, by bubbling up all the problems we got, mostly by pointing out the exceptional values passes to some entities, ah legacy code... again) and proceeding to an appropriate refactoring.

**Problem / Scenario**
Say if I have a type A used by a type B, generally-speaking to throw up an exception from A in the face of B in the case of B is misusing A (e.g. value out of range, etc.), is that really a bad practice? It's supposed to help B to process A in the right way (e.g. passing right arguments to the constructor, etc.). When you look at the .NET framework there are plenty of exceptions when you misuse classes then exceptions are raised and let you know that it's not supposed to work with this or that.

Again, exceptions are supposed to be exceptional but if we take an example of a very simple entity or method parsing an IP address, the .NET Framework gently let you know that the string passed is not okay for that:

```
var address = IPAddress.Parse(@"It makes sense =]");
// An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.dll
// Additional information: An invalid IP address was specified.
```

**Question**
Of course there is always a lot of context to consider and it's not that black and white but do you think that it's a good way to design API to inform the developer that the classes cannot work with this value? (in addition to the documentation, if any) rather than for example returning null when it cannot work, what is the most legitimate? How do you know whether you have to throw an exception or to simply return false / null to express that it cannot work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions should be thrown whenever something does not follow in the intended workflow. For example, if a method is called with incorrect arguments (as in your snippet), if an external resource (such as a file) is not available, or if the application is in a state that does not allow the method to be called.

An exception allows other developers to decide, how far an exception bubbles up before it can be handled gracefully. Furthermore, an exception provides information about what went wrong.

Simply returning null introduces the problem that all return values must be checked for nullness before they can be used. Otherwise, you might end up with null-reference exceptions in places that cause the entire application to crash. Therefore, returning null should only be used more exceptionally than throwing exceptions.

Comment: I agree with you but alas seems this was not enough for my manager while they keep having a lot of issues. Anyway, this seems to be the answer, at least from my point of view.